# Serving file with CouchDB attachment?

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, cradle

Im using Express. i can't figure out how to send an image file to client in a way that it will be displayed to HTML tag `<img src='/preview/?doc=xxxxxx&image=img1.jpg'>`. I'm using Cradle getAttachment function to communicate with Couchdb https://github.com/flatiron/cradle

```
db.getAttachment(id, filename, function (err, reply) {
    set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    res.end(reply);
});
```

i don't know what `reply` is exactly and how to transfer that image to client without buffer

Comment: Actually, `reply` is equal to the contents of the file that got requested via `db.getAttachment`. As binary files happen to be quite large, I guess this variant is supposed to be used for text files mostly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### To transfer an attachment from cradle to a client without buffering, you can *pipe* its *readableStream* to the reponse's *writableStream*.

**The long version**

A variant of cradle's `db.getAttachment` returns a `readableStream` (see [streaming](https://github.com/flatiron/cradle#streaming-2) from cradle's docs). express' `res` object on the other hand serves as a `writableStream`. This means you should be able* to pipe an attachment to it like this:

```
// respond to a request like '/preview/?doc=xxxxxx&image=img1.jpg'
app.get('/preview/', function(req, res){

  // fetch query parameters from url (?doc=...&image=...)
  var id = req.query.doc
  var filename = req.query.image

  // create a readableStream from the doc's attachment
  var readStream = db.getAttachment(id, filename, function (err) { 
    // note: no second argument
    // this inner function will be executed 
    // once the stream is finished
    // or has failed
    if (err)
      return console.dir(err)
    else
      console.dir('the stream has been successfully piped')
  })
  // set the appropriate headers here
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

  // pipe the attachment to the client's response
  readStream.pipe(res)
})
```

---

**Or, slightly shorter:**

```
app.get('/preview/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png")
  db.getAttachment(req.query.doc, req.query.image, someErrorHandlerFunction).pipe(res)
})
```

---

*I'm not at work, so sadly I cannot verify this code will run. Drop me a line if you have problems.